# .Net Adding Specific value to a predefined print page

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, printing

I have a printed page, and i need to add a specific variable value at a specific position in the printed page and re-print it again. So, i will insert the pre-printed page in my printer to print the specific value at a specific position in my pre-printed page. How can i do that in .NET Windows application?

Thanks,
tepu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the builtin graphics library to draw on specific area/place holder(where you want to print) of the page.